# How to delay iron router route lookup

Tags: node.js, meteor, routes, iron-router

Consider the following scenario:

There's a `collection` called `Resources` and a special user can CRUD it on an `admin` site.

When a regular user accesses the site, the routes are created dynamically in the browser depending on a subscription to `Resources`.

We would like to pause the router lookup until the subscription's callback function terminates. Otherwise the user is presented a "404" when accessing `/<dynamically-created-route>` directly.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You create a dynamic route based on a resource id, waitOn a subscription with the id value, and then route based on whether or not you can access the resource with the id. This assumes you have the proper publishing setup in your server code also.

```
Resources = new Mongo.Collection("resources");

Router.route("/resources/:_id", {
  name: "resources",
  waitOn: function() {
    // Waits on the subscription
    return Meteor.subscribe("resources", this.params._id);
  },
  action: function() {
    // Should only return the resource you subscribed to unless you
    // subscribe to resources in another part of your application
    var resource = Resources.findOne({});
    if (resource) {
      // The resource exists and the user is able to access it.
      this.render("resourceTemplate", {
        data: {
          resource: resource
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      Router.go("/404");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey @Curtis. So imagine I would like to create restful endpoints. E.g. If I as an admin add a `Resource` called `Car`, I would like to dynamically generate the following routes:

`GET /cars`,
`GET /car/:id/edit`,
`PUT /car/:id/`

and so on. I am able to generate these routes ones the subscription receives all  the resources so I can comfortably navigate on the page, but accessing `/car/:id/edit` from the browser gives me the 404 as the lookup happens before the subscription terminates.